# npmjs create username that created as organization before

Tags: node.js, npm, package, npm-publish

Recently I created organization in my account, for example 'my_org' so I can publish package under 'my_org' scope. But decided to create separate account (by org's email) with username/scope 'my_org'. So I deleted the organization that I created before then tried to create new account with username that I said. But in register page of npmjs I got this error: 'that scope name is already in use'

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

Solved by help of dear npm support. Sent email to them and described my state. As I said when u create organization/scope in account and after you delete it, you can't create new account same name as organization. I sent email and helped me create new account. I sent my new account's email to them and so on.

Comment: To actually provide an answer to future readers, please share what the solution was and problems you encountered.